# PHP - Recursive Multidimension Array iterator

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive array iterator function in which the function will return a result set of all sets that are specified by '$needle'. Where $needle = key

Here is my function:

```
function recursive($needle, $array, $holder = array()) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (gettype($value) == 'array') {
            if ($key != $needle) {
                recursive($needle, $value);
            } elseif ($key == $needle) {
                if (!empty($value)) {
                    array_push($holder, $value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $holder;
}
```

But I'm not getting all the results back and instead get a few empty results, if I don't specify the `!empty($value)`, although the input array does not have any empty sets. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: array_walk_recursive or array_search and lot more inbuilt function are there

Comment: @ArunKillu Thats irrelevant. Whats wrong with the function I wrote?

Comment: We need an example array and function parameters that trigger your error. Otherwise, one cannot replicate the problem.

Comment: @Sven use any multidimensional array, specify $needle as your key and run the function... Cant be simpler than this

Comment: First thing that looks incomplete: You're assigning matches to $holder but $holder is not passed nor evaluated as a return value when calling recursive() from inside itself.

Comment: You should use `is_array` to avoid type juggling issues: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Comment: @matthias I had originally passed $holder into recursive, but that seemed to be irrelevant

Comment: Apart from the notes, your flapsy comment *"use any multidimensional array"* made me actually do it and It proofs your function working - https://eval.in/private/236c41834864b6 - So at least sometimes :P - What's your concrete question?

Comment: Well, currently your recursive call does not do anything.. It's return value is ignored and it doesn't alter holder. So your whole function behaves as if only the `elseif` branch was there.

Comment: @hakre The only thing I liked from your comment is the word flapsy, which is not a real word. Other than that, as a computer programmer, I try to think logically, and see if my logic is correct instead of just writing wrong code and trying to see if it works.

Comment: @dudemanbearpig: Well actually quite a good point. So print out your code and then try to run it manually with a pencil and describe to your self what happens if your imaginary data passes through. That's the best way to write code in a way "thinking logically" as you've obviously have logical flaws in it already. You need to find those now. It's you're code, those flaws belong to you and nobody is taking them away from you.

Comment: @dudemanbearpig dude relax ;) Taking your frustration out on random internet people won't solve your problems.

Comment: @dudemanbearpig Keep in mind that all answers are posted here voluntary, you should be grateful if people are trying to help, not bash the answers...

Comment: @lethal-guitar I can't pass $holder back in the function, It'll just process the array over and over as many times $needle just returns the entire array over and over..

Comment: The comments on the docs page say a recursive function is way faster than RecursiveIteratorIterator for what it is worth  http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel since PHP has standard [Recursive Iterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) API:

```
//$array is your multi-dimensional array
$result   = [];
$search   = 'foo';
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(
        $array,
        RecursiveArrayIterator::CHILD_ARRAYS_ONLY
    )
); 

foreach($iterator as $key=>$value)
{
   if($search==$key && $value!=='')
   {
      $result[] = $value;
   }
}
```

-note, that, since you're searching for value *by key* - in common case `$value` will hold entire subsection.

If you want to do this in your own recursive function, here's one:

```
function recursive($needle, $array, $holder = []) 
{
    $holder = [];
    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    {
       if($key===$needle && $value!=='')
       {
          $holder = array_merge($holder, [$value]);
       }
       if(is_array($value))
       {
          $holder = array_merge($holder, recursive($needle, $value, $holder));
       }
    }
    return $holder;
}
```

Comment: Actually this is not quite correct. There is the problem that `RecursiveArrayIterator` actually is a `RecursiveArrayAndObjectIterator` which is not what OP is looking or. Just saying.

Comment: @hakre hm. Not sure I got that. Where is the point against Iterator ?

Comment: No point against iterator, just perhaps (perhaps!) the wrong Iterator.

Comment: Good answer. All the people commenting on my question, they're trying to give me life lessons instead of answering the freaking question...

Comment: @dudemanbearpig: Oh good that at least you know when it is answered, because so far the question was not clear to most users. Which aparently is the reason as well that you're seeing life lessons here, just asking you for writing a question.

Comment: well, it might take you some sleepovers until you find the next logical problems with that code, but until then, happy daytime ;)

Comment: That's quite simple: Provide example data and the expected result as well as the actual result next to the code alone. that's also called a self-contained example and if I remember right a requirement when asking a question on Stackoverflow. But it's perhaps only you being too lazy to create a well done example and just comment around and behave as if anybody than you would just be little-minded.

Comment: @AlmaDo: That's such an exemplary Array Iterator: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19710294/367456

Comment: @hakre My array is an array of size 9234 of arrays literllay 4 or 5 levels deep. Cant post that here...

Comment: This is why such questions require you to write an example with example data, that means not the live data, just an example data with as little data as necessary to still demonstrate the issue (same for the code: as little as necessary, re-create from scratch for the example only). I'm sure you can do that, it's just that you didn't thought about doing so.

Comment: what does `$holder = []` means in the function declaration ?

Comment: That means an array holding temporary value (another option would be declaring static local variable - but I'm always against that)

Comment: @hakre You can pass the `RecursiveArrayIterator::CHILD_ARRAYS_ONLY` flag to the `RecursiveArrayIterator` constructor as the second param to make it iterate only on arrays, making it actually `RecursiveOnlyArrayIterator`

Comment: @blackcat - top hint, let me see to edit [the (other) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19710294/367456).

Answer (score 1):

More fine-grained control is perhaps possible with *true* (tm) recursive array traversal via `RecursiveIterator` interface and some key filters and array conversion functions:

```
$needle = '0';
$array  = [[1]];

$it = new KeyFilter(
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new MyRecursiveArrayIterator($array)
        , RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
    )
    , $needle
);

$result = iterator_to_array($it, FALSE);
var_dump($result);
```

Providing an exemplary result as:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    int(1)
  }
  [1] =>
  int(1)
}
```

Full code example ([Demo](https://eval.in/59167)):

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/q/19709410/367456
 */

Class MyRecursiveArrayIterator extends ArrayIterator implements RecursiveIterator
{
    public function hasChildren()
    {
        $current = $this->current();
        return is_array($current) && count($current);
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
        return new self($this->current());
    }
}

class KeyFilter extends RegexIterator
{
    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator, $key)
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $iterator, '/' . preg_quote($key) . '/', NULL, RegexIterator::USE_KEY
        );
    }
}

$needle = '0';
$array  = [[1]];

$it = new KeyFilter(
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new MyRecursiveArrayIterator($array)
        , RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
    )
    , $needle
);

$result = iterator_to_array($it, FALSE);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A tiny modification of your construction:

`$holder = recursive($needle, $value, $holder);`

Ay?

Comment: That only passes the entire array into the function, ending up just spitting back the entire array as many times as it finds $needle...

Comment: Okay, so please be more specific with what you want to achieve with your function. Returning array elements that match your key? Or something else...?

Comment: And by the way: It doesn't pass the "entire array", it passes $holder which is initialized as empty array and then modified when (key == $needle) matches occur and those subsequent elements are pushed to it. As you said "a result set of all sets"...