# PHP: RecursiveArrayIterator not working

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

This is my array:

```
$wp_session = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'id2' => $id2,
    'p1' => $p1,
    'p2' => $p2
);
```

The result was giving me a `Recursive_ArrayAccess` so I searched on how to fix it and came across these answers:

[PHP - Recursive Multidimension Array iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709410/php-recursive-multidimension-array-iterator)
[PHP foreach() with arrays within arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524227/php-foreach-with-arrays-within-arrays)

So I added/changed my foreach statement to:

```
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($wp_session); 

    //Split the parameters with &
    foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
            if(!empty($value)){
                $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
            }
            //Remove the last &
            $fields2 = substr($fields, 0, -1);
    }
```

But then the page breaks.

I also tried:

```
    $iterator = array_walk_recursive($wp_session);
```

The page doesn't break but $fields2 is not outputting the data in the next foreach statement. This is the whole code:

```
    //Start a session

    $wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();

    //Get the current parameters

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $id2 = $_GET['id2'];
    $p1 = $_GET['p1'];
    $p2 = $_GET['p2'];
    $wp_session = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'id2' => $id2,
        'p1' => $p1,
        'p2' => $p2
    );

    //array_walk_recursive($wp_session);
    //$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($wp_session); 
    $iterator = array_walk_recursive($wp_session);

    //Split the parameters with &
    foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
            if(!empty($value)){
                $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
            }
            //Remove the last &
            $fields2 = substr($fields, 0, -1);
    }

    if( is_admin() )
        return $items;

    //Get the menu items and add the above parameters to the menu items urls

    foreach( $items as $item ) 
    {
        if($wp_session){
            $item->url .= '?' . $fields2;
        }
    }
    return $items;
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong? Any kind of help or suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Its breaking because you missed the closing `)` for `RecursiveIteratorIterator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But then the page breaks.

That page has to break:

```
 $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($wp_session);
```

Count the number of `(` and then the number of `)` and then start using a good IDE. If you still didn't get the hint, you are 1 `)` short on that line.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see it. Will find a better editor. Can I ask, why isn't `array_walk_recursive($wp_session);` passing the data to the next foreach statement?

Comment: Because you are not using that function as it is supposed to. Seems like there is any misunderstanding. This is what that function does: `array_walk_recursive — Apply a user function recursively to every member of an array` But you are sending it only 1 parameter :)

Answer (score 2):

Overkill, it seems you simply want to create a parameter string from the array.

There's [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) for that:

`$fields = http_build_query($wp_session);`

<kbd>**[See it in action](http://codepad.org/GlMuaEyg)**</kbd>

Comment: I didn't really go through the whole code they have but if that is really what they want to do then that's really a big overkill. Almost funny too :) +1