# CodeIgniter multidimensional array store in mysql database single column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I am trying to store this data in database but i am getting error. how to fix this?

**I want simply store multidimensional array in a single column.**

```
$data = array(
            '2017' => array(
                '6' => array(
                    '10' => array(
                        'count' => 76
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );

$getdata = $this->view_count->setView($data);
```

**Model**

```
public function setView($data)
    {
        $setData = $this->db->where('short', 'honwl')->update('ci_links', $data['view_count']);
        return $setData;
    }
```

Error which i am getting
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: view_count

Filename: models/View_count.php

Line Number: 14

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp\www\blog\application\models\View_count.php
Line: 14
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\wamp\www\blog\application\controllers\Dashbord.php
Line: 52
Function: setView

File: C:\wamp\www\blog\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A Database Error Occurred

You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Filename: C:/wamp/www/blog/system/database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 1864

Answer (score 0):

As message says, you don't have key `$data['view_count']` but you have `$data[2017][6][10]['count']` value. I asume those dates are changed dynamically so you need to get value of inner array by key `count`.
If your array always has similar keys i.e. `$data[year][month][day][count]`, you can use code (bit modified) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709410/php-recursive-multidimension-array-iterator#answer-19709646) to get that key value. Put in your model

```
private function getCount($arr, $search)
{
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr)); 
    foreach($iterator as $key => $value) {
        if($search == $key && $value !== '') {
            return $value;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then in your first method use value filtered through this function:

```
public function setView($data)
{
    $count = $this->getCount($data, 'count');

    if ($count !== false) {
        $setData = $this->db->where('short', 'honwl')->update('ci_links', $count);
        return $setData;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: $data = array(
   '2017' => array(
    '6' => array(
     '10' => array(
      'count' => 76
     ),
     '11' => array(
      'count' => 42
     ),
     '15' => array(
      'count' => 23
     ),
    ),
   ),
  );

I want simply store multidimensional array in a single column.

Comment: Seems I answered to ["Y" part of problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#answer-66378)?

Answer (score 0):

According to you example code, you can encode array data to JSON for saving to column, then get back by decode:

**Controller:**

```
$data = array(
            '2017' => array(
                '6' => array(
                    '10' => array(
                        'count' => 76
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );

$getdata = $this->view_count->setView($data);
$data = $this->view_count->getView();
```

**Model:**

```
public function setView($data)
{
    $data = json_encode($data);
    $setData = $this->db->where('short', 'honwl')->update('ci_links', array('column_name'=>$data));
    return $setData;
}

public function getView($data)
{
    $row = $this->db->where('short', 'honwl')->get('ci_links')->row();
    return json_decode($row->column_name, true);
}
```

The `column_name` depends on your table's column name that save the array data.