# Codeigniter - It's possible multidimensional array data store inside a single mysql column?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

Multidimensional array data store inside a single mysql column.

**Here it is my data. How to store it inside a single mysql column?**

Someone tell me the solution with example code.

```
$data = array(
        '2017' => array(
            '6' => array(
                '10' => array(
                    'count' => 76
                ),
                '11' => array(
                    'count' => 42
                ),
                '15' => array(
                    'count' => 23
                ),
            ),
            '7' => array(
                '5' => array(
                    'count' => 26
                ),
                '25' => array(
                    'count' => 82
                ),
                '26' => array(
                    'count' => 53
                ),
            ),
        ),
        '2018' => array(
            '6' => array(
                '18' => array(
                    'count' => 30
                )
            )
        ),
    );
```

Comment: mysql 5.7 and choose datatype as JSON and convert the array into JSON and store.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter multidimensional array store in mysql database single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475620/codeigniter-multidimensional-array-store-in-mysql-database-single-column)

Comment: You can serialize it and store in column. At time of retrival you can unserialize it. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: So you have no intention of executing any kind analytical query against this array?

Answer (score 1):

Have your column to type **text** for longer data.
then use

```
$data = json_encode($data);
```

then store that $data.

Later, to get it. just use decode:

```
$data = json_decode($data); // Alternately json_decode($data,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) array to string for saving database also:

```
$stringData = serialize($data);
```

then you can [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) back to array:

```
$data = unserialize($stringData );
```

Answer (score 0):

[`serialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) converts a PHP array or object to a string. [`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) converts that string into whatever it was stored as.